# Do-while loop not running

Tags: c#, do-while

I apologize for the swdish names in the code.
I am trying to make a program that asks the user to chose a soda, then the amount of bottles.
the user should be able to make choices until the amount reaches 24 bottles.

When i run my code i can make one or two chioces then the program exits.

This is for an assignment that i need to hand in this evening so im quite stressed out at the moment.

i do not expect you to answer with the solution but please point me in the right direction.

All the best!

My code:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Välj läsk att lägga till i backen:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Coca Cola");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Fanta");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Sprite");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Red bull");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Ramlösa");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Hallonsoda");


            int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int antalLäsk = 0;
            do
            {

                if (menyVal == 1)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Coca Cola i backen!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                    antalLäsk = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
                else if (menyVal == 2)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Fanta i backen!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                    antalLäsk = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
                else if (menyVal == 3)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Sprite i backen!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                    antalLäsk = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
                else if (menyVal == 4)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till red bull i backen!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                    antalLäsk = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                    antalLäsk++;
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
                else if (menyVal == 5)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till ramlösa i backen!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                    antalLäsk = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
                else if (menyVal == 6)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Hallonsoda i backen!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                    antalLäsk = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt menyval!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
            } while (antalLäsk >= 24);
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Backen är full!");
                Console.WriteLine("Programmet avslutas!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

Comment: you are always overriding the variable antalLäsk  with the new user input instead of adding them.

Comment: I don't get the logic here. The loop only runs as long as antalLäsk is greater or equal 24 : `antalLäsk >= 24`, So if the number entered is smaller, the loop exits. Did you mean less than or equal? `antalLäsk <= 24`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `while` loop you should ask for input from the user as you did in the if statements.

```
menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Moreover, for each iteration, you need to add +1 to antalLäsk and not override its value by assigning the output the user typed.

Lastly, the second time it will run it will not run the "do" statement, it will only run the while statement. In order to fix it, you can switch to a `for` loop (without do), and then you can have an index counter instead of `antalLäsk`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added return statement in each if block which needs to be removed.
Also, you might want to display the count of bottles separately.
So store the user input from each

```
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

to a different variable, rather than to antalLäsk and then add the value from it, like

```
 var userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
 antalLäsk += userInput;
```

Most importantly your loop is working on incorrect condition
here the following

```
(antalLäsk >= 24);
```

should be

```
(antalLäsk < 24);
```

also it looks like you want the menu to change everytime, so this statement should be inside the do block.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Välj läsk att lägga till i backen:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Coca Cola");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Fanta");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Sprite");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Red bull");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Ramlösa");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Hallonsoda");

            int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

so your updated code would be, though this can be refactored but it will be sufficient for you:

```
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Välj läsk att lägga till i backen:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Coca Cola");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Fanta");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Sprite");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Red bull");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Ramlösa");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Hallonsoda");

            int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (menyVal == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Coca Cola i backen!");
                Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                var userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                antalLäsk += userInput;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (menyVal == 2)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Fanta i backen!");
                Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                var userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + userInput);
                antalLäsk += userInput;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (menyVal == 3)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Sprite i backen!");
                Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                var userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                antalLäsk += userInput;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (menyVal == 4)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till red bull i backen!");
                Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                var userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                antalLäsk += userInput;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (menyVal == 5)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till ramlösa i backen!");
                Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                var userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                antalLäsk += userInput;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (menyVal == 6)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Hallonsoda i backen!");
                Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
                var userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till" + antalLäsk);
                antalLäsk += userInput;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt menyval!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        } while (antalLäsk < 24);
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Backen är full!");
            Console.WriteLine("Programmet avslutas!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little bit, I added some Console input checking with `int.TryParse` and I removed the unnecessary repeating of `Console.WriteLine` inside every `if`/`if else` clause. Also you have to sum the values from the Console input for `antalLäsk` like did with `antalLäsk += amount;` and the while condition should be `while (antalLäsk <= 24)`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    int menyVal = 0;
    int antalLäsk = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Välj läsk att lägga till i backen:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Coca Cola");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Fanta");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Sprite");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Red bull");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Ramlösa");
        Console.WriteLine("6. Hallonsoda");

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menyVal))
        {
            Console.Clear();
            if (menyVal == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Coca Cola i backen!");
            }
            else if (menyVal == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Fanta i backen!");
            }
            else if (menyVal == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Sprite i backen!");
            }
            else if (menyVal == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till red bull i backen!");
            }
            else if (menyVal == 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till ramlösa i backen!");
            }
            else if (menyVal == 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till Hallonsoda i backen!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong input! Try again");
                Console.ReadKey();
                continue;
            }
                    
            Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong input! Try again");
                Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");
            }

            antalLäsk += amount;
            Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till " + antalLäsk);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktigt menyval!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    } while (antalLäsk <= 24);

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Backen är full!");
    Console.WriteLine("Programmet avslutas!");
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not *repeat yourself* and keep things simple (split the monolith into lesser rutines).
First of all, let's *extract data*:

```
// I've chosen IReadOnlyList in order to be protected from occasional 
// data changing; but you can put List<string> or array (string[])   
static IReadOnlyList<string> drinks = new List<string>() {
  "Coca Cola",
  "Fanta",
  "Sprite",
  "Red bull",
  "Ramlösa",
  "Hallonsoda",
};
```

Then we can put:

```
int antalLäsk = 0;

// While we have less than 24 bottles (in total)...
while (antalLäsk <= 24) {
  Console.Clear();
  Console.WriteLine("Välj läsk att lägga till i backen:");

  // Menu 
  for (int i = 0; i < drinks.Count; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {drinks[i]}"); 

  // User selects drink
  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int menyVal) || menuVal < 1 || menuVal > drinks.Count) {
    // if selection is invalid (not a integer or out of range)
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, incorrect menu position. Please, try again");

    continue; 
  }

  Console.Clear();
  Console.WriteLine($"Du har lagt till {drinks[menuVal - 1]} i backen!");
  Console.WriteLine("Hur många vill du lägga till?");

  // User selects number of bottles, again we have to validate the input
  while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int bottles) || bottles < 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number of bottles, please try again");
  } 

  antalLäsk += bottles; 
      
  Console.WriteLine($"Du har lagt till {antalLäsk}");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```